# Git reports large file error despite using Git LFS

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-lfs

This is the folder I'm trying to add to my GitHub as a repository.  As you can see, Train.csv and TrainAndValid.csv exceed GitHub's 100MB limit.  To fix this, I decided to use Git LFS.

[image: This]

In the Git Bash, I typed the following commands:

`git lfs install`

`git lfs track "*.csv"`

`git add .gitattributes`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "initial commit"`

`git push origin master`

And yet I am still getting this error:

```
$ git push origin master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (9/9), 295 MB | 6.6 MB/s, done
Enumerating objects: 35, done.
Counting objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 21.92 MiB | 867.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 35 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: a4d4a1226ddf41ba822466d7d44d9a85
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Train/Train.csv is 110.63 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File TrainAndValid.csv is 113.85 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/oo92/blue-book-bulldozers-kaggle.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/oo92/blue-book-bulldozers-kaggle.git'
```

Comment: are you sure you have only one commit on master now? Maybe you have a first commit with the big files, and only the second commit where you convert them to lfs ?

Comment: That could be the case.  How can I clear all commits?

Comment: since you just start a new repository, I would recommend: `rm -rf .git` and then `git init` , then start over...

Comment: I decided to divide the dataset in half but I'll keep what you're saying in mind in the future.  Dividing the dataset made more sense because I am using the raw link to access the data through Python.