# How do I use Git LFS in Android Studio (Windows)?

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control, git-lfs

An included sqlite database shipped with my Android app is now larger than 100 MB, so GitHub (GH) rejects my `push` of the updated file via Android Studio's (AS) version control. I can't currently reduce this file below the 100 Mb limit and it's required for the app. I've installed Git-LFS and taken the following steps via AS Terminal:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.db"
git lfs track "app/src/main/assets/*.db"
git add .gitattributes
```

When I try to `push` the updated database via AS, the `push` is rejected and the AS Console message is:

> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
> remote: error: File app/src/main/assets/frequency.db is 138.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

Local `commit`s seem to work fine.

Before the database grew above 100 MB, `commit`s and `push`es to GH worked fine via AS, so I assume I have AS configured properly for version control using GH. Also, this means previous versions of the database (those below the 100 MB limit) are in my GitHub repository. I'd like to retain those versions in GH if possible.

Android Studio version: Artic Fox, 2020.3.1 patch 3 (Windows), with Git and GitHub bundled plugins enabled

**How do I use Git-LFS in Android Studio?** Is there a different git plug-in I should install? Is there a configuration/setting change I need to make in AS?

I've reviewed the following SO questions, but virtually none of them discuss using Git-LFS in AS:

1. [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted)
2. [git-lfs command not found webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466162/git-lfs-command-not-found-webstorm/68742495#68742495)
3. [not able to push file more than 100mb to git hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586977/not-able-to-push-file-more-than-100mb-to-git-hub)
4. [Files too large warning in Github Desktop after configuring Git LFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395438/files-too-large-warning-in-github-desktop-after-configuring-git-lfs)
5. [Staged git lfs files not being intercepted by git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931154/staged-git-lfs-files-not-being-intercepted-by-git-lfs?rq=1)
6. [Git reports large file error despite using Git LFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024583/git-reports-large-file-error-despite-using-git-lfs)

I've also reviewed the following, but there is no discussion of using Git-LFS in AS:

1. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github
2. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
3. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro#version_control_basics